# slice text in textbox after newline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I have a textbox in reactjs. I want to slice its contents by new lines, outputting an array.

For example, if the textbox has

```
foo
bar
foobar
```

I want to get

```
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
```

Any ways I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\n means new line, I suggest trimming the text before splitting.

```
string.trim().split('\n')
```

***UPDATE***

as @Wyck suggest, if you need to remove the empty space around each line, you need to map each item and trim it.

```
string.trim().split('\n').map(s => s.trim())
```

Comment: I suspect the purpose of calling `trim()` first is to remove an ultimate trailing newline character if it exists.  `"A\nB\n".trim()` results in `"A\nB"`.  This untrimmed string when split, would result in an array of three elements, `[ "A", "B", "" ]` whereas the trimmed string would result in an array of only two elements `[ "A", "B" ]`.

Comment: @Wyck Thanks for your comment, but "A\nB\n".trim().split('\n'); will create an aray of two elements [ "A", "B" ] not [ "A", "B", "" ]

Comment: Exactly what I said, no?  Perhaps my reference to "this untrimmed string" was not as clear as saying `"A\nB\n"`.  and me saying "the trimmed string" was not as clear as me saying `"A\nB\n".trim()`, which is equivalent to `"A\nB"`.

Comment: Yes, exactly the trimming is to remove the space around the actual text, as maybe the file which he wants to get its lines has a space after the last new line, ex: 'A\nB\n '.split() will generate an array of three elements, So no need for the third element ( which is empty space ).

Comment: I was worried you were going to say that.  If your goal of calling `trim()` is to remove _spaces_, then you should trim each item _after_ splitting, because there could be spaces before the newlines as well, but trimming after will still leave empty items, which can be filtered out with `filter` or something.  Overall, I think your suggestion of `trim`, given your clarified intent, complicates what is permissible syntax of the input and doesn't handle all cases (of your modified intent) robustly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but he didn't ask for trimming the spacing, it was just a suggestion, maybe he wants spaces, anyway, he knew the concept and he can do what he need.

Comment: Maybe I can update the answer with your suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

for that, you just need to use 'split' function with '\n' which will help you separate the text.

codesandbox example : https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-murdock-0rmku2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

We can use [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method here

```js
str ="foo\nbar\nfoobar"
 
console.log(str.split("\n"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).